# SElinux and TCP Traceroute

Tags: centos, security, selinux

I need to run a TCP Traceroute in the browser but are getting a few SElinux alerts.

I have tried creating a policy with `audit2allow`, e.g `ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute` and `semodule -i my-traceroute.pp` which removes the alerts but the traceroute still does not work and returns the message:
`traceroute to example.com (93.184.216.34), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets↵"],…] 0: ["traceroute to example.com (93.184.216.34), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets↵"] 1: ["send: Permission denied↵"`.
There are no AVC alerts after I add these policies. Just that `send: Permission denied↵` message sent back from the server.

I've even tried to create my own policy e.g

```
module traceroute 1.0;

require {
type httpd_t;
class capability net_raw;
class rawip_socket { getopt create setopt write read };
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t self:capability net_raw;
allow httpd_t self:rawip_socket { getopt create setopt write read };
```

and

```
checkmodule -M -m -o traceroute.mod traceroute.tt
semodule_package -o traceroute.pp -m traceroute.mod
semodule -i traceroute.pp
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

If I set SElinux to `permissive` the traceroute runs without issue.

Note: I have already set capabilities to allow traceroute to run as non-root user e.g Set cap_net_raw+ep on /usr/bin/traceroute

Any ideas??

Alerts:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/traceroute from create access on the rawip_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed create access on rawip_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ rawip_socket ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   /usr/bin/traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages           traceroute-2.0.22-2.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   2
First Seen                    2019-03-05 15:45:17 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      a747c347-fced-47ae-a1e8-97753dfde465

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.735:1108250): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=rawip_socket permissive=1


type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.735:1108250): avc:  denied  { net_raw } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" capability=13  scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551801996.735:1108250): arch=x86_64 syscall=socket success=yes exit=ESRCH a0=2 a1=3 a2=6 a3=7ffea5135e60 items=0 ppid=24121 pid=24122 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=traceroute exe=/usr/bin/traceroute subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,httpd_t,rawip_socket,create

-----------------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/traceroute from bind access on the rawip_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed bind access on rawip_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ rawip_socket ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   /usr/bin/traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages           traceroute-2.0.22-2.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   10
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:38 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      82af42ef-6a01-4a8f-84da-79e2119e65b3

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.735:1108251): avc:  denied  { bind } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" lport=6 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=rawip_socket permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.735:1108251): avc:  denied  { node_bind } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:node_t:s0 tclass=rawip_socket permissive=1

type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551801996.735:1108251): arch=x86_64 syscall=bind success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=7ffea5136340 a2=1c a3=7ffea5135da0 items=0 ppid=24121 pid=24122 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=traceroute exe=/usr/bin/traceroute subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,httpd_t,rawip_socket,bind

---------------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/traceroute from setopt access on the rawip_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed setopt access on rawip_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ rawip_socket ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   /usr/bin/traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages           traceroute-2.0.22-2.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   1
First Seen                    2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      104114b1-9024-412d-a195-57eef1be45e3

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108252): avc:  denied  { setopt } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" lport=6 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=rawip_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108252): arch=x86_64 syscall=setsockopt success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=a a3=7ffea5136398 items=0 ppid=24121 pid=24122 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=traceroute exe=/usr/bin/traceroute subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,httpd_t,rawip_socket,setopt

------------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/traceroute from connect access on the rawip_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed connect access on rawip_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ rawip_socket ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   /usr/bin/traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages           traceroute-2.0.22-2.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   10
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:38 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      ad1eedfa-b54a-4dfb-b719-3d402a686d95

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108253): avc:  denied  { connect } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" lport=6 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=rawip_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108253): arch=x86_64 syscall=connect success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=60f4d0 a2=1c a3=7ffea5135e60 items=0 ppid=24121 pid=24122 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=traceroute exe=/usr/bin/traceroute subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,httpd_t,rawip_socket,connect

-----------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/traceroute from getattr access on the rawip_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed getattr access on rawip_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ rawip_socket ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   /usr/bin/traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages           traceroute-2.0.22-2.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   10
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:38 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      cdd75a7d-152b-49fe-a7c8-b9e437655d63

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108254): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" laddr=167.86.68.164 lport=6 faddr=93.184.216.34 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=rawip_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108254): arch=x86_64 syscall=getsockname success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=7ffea5136400 a2=7ffea51363fc a3=7ffea5135e60 items=0 ppid=24121 pid=24122 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=traceroute exe=/usr/bin/traceroute subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,httpd_t,rawip_socket,getattr

------------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/traceroute from getopt access on the rawip_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed getopt access on rawip_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ rawip_socket ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   /usr/bin/traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages           traceroute-2.0.22-2.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   1
First Seen                    2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      97c5dfcd-ffe3-48e4-83ef-dfc526487bba

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108255): avc:  denied  { getopt } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" laddr=167.86.68.164 lport=6 faddr=93.184.216.34 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=rawip_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108255): arch=x86_64 syscall=getsockopt success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=e a3=7ffea51363f8 items=0 ppid=24121 pid=24122 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=traceroute exe=/usr/bin/traceroute subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,httpd_t,rawip_socket,getopt

---------------

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/traceroute from read access on the file tcp_ecn.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed read access on the tcp_ecn file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:sysctl_net_t:s0
Target Objects                tcp_ecn [ file ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   /usr/bin/traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   10
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:38 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      8f5dab14-4937-4ca5-abc8-23c0c5cb12f3

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108256): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" name="tcp_ecn" dev="proc" ino=5310982 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:sysctl_net_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1


Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,sysctl_net_t,file,read

----------------

SELinux is preventing traceroute from open access on the file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_ecn.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that traceroute should be allowed open access on the tcp_ecn file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute
# semodule -i my-traceroute.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:sysctl_net_t:s0
Target Objects                /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_ecn [ file ]
Source                        traceroute
Source Path                   traceroute
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   3
First Seen                    2019-03-04 13:32:25 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-05 16:06:36 GMT
Local ID                      7f65540c-60f9-4566-8ab7-52d4f48d6389

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551801996.736:1108256): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=24122 comm="traceroute" path="/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_ecn" dev="proc" ino=5310982 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:sysctl_net_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1


Hash: traceroute,httpd_t,sysctl_net_t,file,open
```

Comment: Yes, The request is sent using ajax and it returns the message "socket: Permission denied↵". I'll update the OP to make this more clear.

Comment: Correction. With the `audit2allow` policies installed the message is: `"traceroute to example.com (93.184.216.34), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets↵"],…]
0: ["traceroute to example.com (93.184.216.34), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets↵"]
1: ["send: Permission denied↵"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out myself so I'll answer my own question.

The answer was to do both of the things I'd already tried in the OP, but use them together.
Previously I had only tried using `audit2allow` to create the policies and when it didn't work disabled those policies and attempted to create my own.

So, to get it working first use `audit2allow` to create a policy from the alerts.
`ausearch -c 'traceroute' --raw | audit2allow -M my-traceroute`
then run
`semodule -i my-traceroute.pp`

Then create another custom policy which basically permits the opening of raw IP sockets for non-root users, that are required for executing the traceroute command.

Create a file called traceroute.tt and add the following to it:

```
module traceroute 1.0;

require {
type httpd_t;
class capability net_raw;
class rawip_socket { getopt create setopt write read };
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t self:capability net_raw;
allow httpd_t self:rawip_socket { getopt create setopt write read };
```

Then run the following commands (as root user):

```
checkmodule -M -m -o traceroute.mod traceroute.tt
semodule_package -o traceroute.pp -m traceroute.mod
semodule -i traceroute.pp
```

Done :)